# Tuple list as key of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple list, File2, that its value is as below:

```
   (1,2,[3,4],2)
   (3,5,[2,3,4,5,6,7],3)
```

I also have data frame that has a column named "Count" and I want to build a dictionary that have my tuple list as key and "Count" column as value:

```
   File3 = dict(zip(File2,df.Count))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
   unhashable type: 'list'
```

Could you please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: A simple workaround is to use `str(your_key)` as the actual key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[3,4]` in `(1,2,[3,4],2)` is a list.  Lists aren't hashable, and only hashable objects may be the keys of dictionaries.  To turn all lists into tuples, you can write a function like

```
def make_tuples(l):
    return tuple(make_tuples(i) if isinstance(i,list) else i for i in l)
```

The above fails if there is a tuple that contains a tuple that contains a list.  That's probably not going to come up, but in that case do

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
def make_tuples(l):
    return tuple(make_tuples(i) if isinstance(i, Sequence) else i for i in l)
```

Comment: If performance is an issue and you are certain the list is only one level deep change the return to `return tuple(tuple(i) if isinstance(i,list) else i for i in l)`